# Is it possible to use a local, selfmade CSS document in Twig templates?

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I try to program a website and use Symfony and Twig for that. I had a CSS document on my computer that I wanted to use, but the base template won't load the CSS, only the HTML so it looks pretty bad.
What can I do?

Comment: Didn't "the *new user* guidance" nudge you to include code giving results you lament? Anyway, please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

the easiest(most brutal) way  is
put style.css  in public folder and connect it in twig

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but you should read
https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/templates.html
to see how it should be done  "in the right way "